# using ajax i am binding kendo grid in the date column it returns kendo grid returns /Date(1403789061723)/?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

using ajax i am binding kendo grid in the date column it returns kendo grid returns  /Date(1403789061723)/ other Fields are binding properly.In case of Normal binding its working perfectly.is there any way to fix this error...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The first thing I would ask is what is the model structure of your data that is being presented back to the grid.

I suspect that you are using a complex model that is not flattened eg. You have some custom classes with multiple properties within them.

If this is the case the grid and the datasource can not figure out what the actual data type is and treats anything not at the top level of data as a string.

To get around this either flatten out the viewmodel data that is being assigned to the grid or use the parsing functions to present the date back. Something like this should work:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Date).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format(\"{0:ddd, dd MMM yyyy}\",kendo.parseDate(Date))#")
```

Obviously putting what ever date time format you want.

Comment: Note that client side filtering and sorting may not work as expected in these complex scenarios. I only know this as I went through a similar issue a few weeks back.